# Google Sheets Script MailApp include cell formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

searched this and I need this code. The problem is I dont know how to run the code and I cannot also comment due to my low reputation.

I have a button on my google sheets where I will assign the code. My data range is

```
var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Front").getRange("C2:Q14")
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{

  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '',{htmlBody : HTML});
}

function doGet()

{
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Front-User").getRange("C2:Q14")

  var emailAddress = 'test@gmail.com'
  var subject = 'Test'
  convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, emailAddress, subject);
}
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Is your question in regards to how to assign code to a button in Google Sheets?

Comment: Hi, I know how to assign the code. The problem is I copy the code and put the doGet function but it does not send an email

Comment: Can you include all of the code that you're currently using in your script?

Comment: hi @ScottMcC here you go. I just copied what code posted on the link

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: hi @abielita, I already posted the code I used and the problem I am encountering.

Comment: @Reymond The code that you have described is pretty advanced. Did you write it yourself, or was it given to you? Is someone else wrote it, have you asked them for help? If you want help here, then you must share your sheet, &/or explain the problem in more detail &/or disclose where you got the code (so we can check if there's any additional information). Unless of course, you got the code but you don't know anything about scripts - is that the problem?